# RDLC subreport inside subreport

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

[Output Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPAs7.png)

[Row Grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvH0Z.png)

I am trying to create a report to match exactly as in attached file using RDLC, that has three levels of data:

1. Packing No
2. PO No
3. Item

Level 2 and 3 should come in a single column, to achive this I have tried using  subreport:

1. Column Grouping - If more than one PO arrives, column is repeating horizontaly instead of extending vertically
2. Row Grouping - Two columns are created one for PO No, another for item details,instead on single column
3. Subreport inside subreport - Here first subreport have Packing No as Parameter, second subreport has Packing No & Po No as parameter, in this case first row of RDLC alone displays all data correctly, subsequent rows are not able to receive the  parameter and it displays error.

I came close but not able to complete, any solution will be greatly helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating things and don't need to place sub-report inside sub-report.

I can see that it might be needed to place (one column report with row grouping by PO#) sub-report into details cell of column 2 and pass package No to it as a parameters to filter data.

Comment: I have already tried this which results in multiple column, one for PO# & another for Item details, attached a image [Row Grouping] for your reference

Comment: You just need to delete that column (note - chose to delete column only, not group) and use row header for group instead.

Comment: Our team is now happy with Row Grouping format. Tks